# Use channel search parameter with grid fields

Tags: channel-entries, grid, entries

I need to filter entries basing on `grid` field.
If grid field is filled the entries will be shown. But I can't do that because seems that is not supported by `search` parameter. This doesn't works:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="notizie" limit="10" search:immagine_principale:immagine="not IS_EMPTY"}
```

where `immagine_pricipale` is a grid field.

How can I solve it?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the [Low Search Results tag](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/tags#results-tag) as a replacement for the Channel Entries tag, you can use that exact syntax thanks to the [Field Search filter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#field-search). As far as I know, there's no native way to filter entries like that.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to set the field and at least one of its columns as searchable. The values of the chosen column will be concatenated on a database column specially to be searched.

Answer (score -1):

You can use search on the grid field tag pair, like:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="notizie"}

    {!--grid field--}
    {immagine_principale 
        search:immagine="not IS_EMPTY"
        limit="10"
    }
        {!--content...--}
    {/immagine_principale}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

[ee grid search parameter in docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/grid.html#search-column-name)

Comment: I took this question "Use channel search parameter with grid fields" (from the title) to apply to searching within each entry's grid values, but I can see how it could more apply to searching entries by a grid value, as in Low's answer.