# Use Channel Entries Search to Search Grid Field?

Tags: channel-entries, search

See: [Use channel search parameter with grid fields](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/24107/use-channel-search-parameter-with-grid-fields)

The answer suggests that there is no way to search for grid field values. Is this still the case until now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct. The easiest way to do it is with the excellent [Low Search addon](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search) and use the [Low Search Results tag](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/tags#results-tag) as a drop in replacement for the {exp:channel:entries} tag and use the [Field Search filter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#field-search) as described.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to set the field and at least one of its columns as searchable. The values of the chosen column will be concatenated on a database column specially to be searched.